# Вызов метода после возвращения в приложение

Tags: android, activity

Есть такая проблема: в приложении мне нужно обновлять данные после того, как пользователь свернул приложение, а потом развернул. Я пробовал кидать метод в onResume и onRestart, но эти методы вызываются и при смене ориентации и при блокировке экрана. Со сменой ориентации я решил проблему, но не получается решить проблему с блокировкой. Может есть какой то другой способ решить данную проблему, либо обойти вызовы состояний активити после разблокировки экрана

Comment: вы вызываете другое приложение или нужно если пользователь сам перехедит на любое другое приложение и потом возврашается? если первый вариант то вы можете через OnActivityResult() решить

Comment: @SaidolimDjuraev, нет, я другое приложение не вызываю. Простая ситуация: приложение было свернуто и потом вновь развернуто

Comment: Блокировка это то же самое сворачивание приложения, с точки зрения жизненного цикла разницы никакой. Почему Вам так важно их различать?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, для того, чтобы пользователь, когда разблокировал экран, не видел прогрессбара с обновлением данных, который я хочу вызывать при разворачивании приложения. Плюс, при блокировке экрана onRestart и onResume вызываются многократно

Comment: А что входящий звонок и еще миллион событий, которые "задвинут" Ваше приложение в стек? По-моему, Вы излишне усложняете. Введите минимальный интервал, скажем 1 минута. Если пользователь вернулся без вызова onCreate() и минимальный интервал не прошел -- никакого прогрессбара.

Answer (score 1):

Создайте переменную для хранения последовательности изменения состояний например в SharedPreferences.

И отслеживай последовательность вызовов например onPause -> onResume,это значит что девайс разблокирован.

При создании и уничтожении Activity, обнуляй.

Comment: еще это значит, что девайс повернули .. что выдвинута хардварная клава .. сменили язык системы и кучу других вещей.

Comment: При повороте девайса последовательности onPause -> onResume  не  будет, будет  onPause()  onStop() Destroy()  onCreate()  onStart()  onResume()

Comment: Такая же последовательность вызовов при блокировке экрана